# We are detected that one or more of the app bundles included in this release are using the following Play Billing Library AIDL

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

I am using the latest version of Google Play Billing 6.2.0. I just add the billing library to Gradle and upload to the internal release because I want to set IAP prices and implement billing in my app. When I upload my app to internal release it gives the error as shown in the title. Anyone with a solution would be appreciated.

I try to add meta to the manifest file. I added a billing expression to the manifest file which is not necessary but I didn't get out of this error.